# Is it technically possible to stop user from changing the original launcher in anyway?

Tags: android, launcher

As there are many different launchers either on IOS or Play Store. My question is if I were a smartphone maker, and I want the people who buy my smartphone are not able to change the original launcher even if users are able to download the launcher. Is it technically possible to stop users from changing the original launcher in any way?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phGMH.png)

Comment: Launcher defaults are chosen at the system level, so I'm sure you could. Seems like something you'd never want to do through.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but just curiousity, why would you suggest that I would never want to do it?

Comment: Because being the only Android smartphone manufacturer to restrict launcher choice wouldn't be a great selling point.